# why my third query is not running?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","automated_ballot_voting") or die("died");
mysqli_select_db($link,"automated_ballot_voting") or die("diewd");

$sql="INSERT INTO automated_ballot_voting.voter VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$dateob','$sx','$ag','$stats','$prov','$citi','$cnc','')";
mysqli_query($link, $sql);                      

mysqli_multi_query($link,$sql);

$query= "select concat(sex,substr(cnic,1,3),Substr(firstname,1,3),length(city),length(province),Substr(city,1,2)) from voter where cnic='$cnc'";
mysqli_multi_query($link,$query);

$result = mysqli_use_result($link);
$row= mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$id=$row[0];


echo "This is your voting ID"."<br>" ; 
echo "<h1>".$id."</h1>"."<br>";
echo "Save it for later use"."<br>";
echo "Thanks" ;
$que= "insert into voter (id) values ('$id')";
mysqli_multi_query($link, $que);

 mysqli_free_result($result);
  mysqli_close($link);

    ?>
```

I want to use the result from second query which is $query that is stored in $id in the third query $que but the third query wont even run, can anyone please help?

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_multi_query`?  Why are you running the first query twice, using *both* `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_multi_query`?

Comment: You really should RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php. None of your code requires "multi". And on top of all that, you're probably vulnerable to sql injection attacks as well.

Comment: What does "third query wont even run" mean?  Do you see any errors?  Why aren't you doing error checking?  `$ran = mysqli_multi_query($link, $que);  if($ran === FALSE){ echo mysqli_error($link); }`

Comment: P.S. This code is **extremely** unsafe!  `mysqli_multi_query` lets you run multiple queries in one SQL string.  `mysqli_query` disallows that.  What would happen if I decided to sign up with a `fname` of `'); DROP TABLE voter; -- `?